# Using a provider in another provider and vice versa

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have two providers, I'm injecting them through constructor.

**user-data.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserDataProvider {

  constructor(private apiService: ApiServiceProvider) {
  }
```

**api-service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiServiceProvider {

  constructor(private userData: UserDataProvider) {
  }
```

I need to use methods from one provider in another and vice versa. This approach now gives me error

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for UserDataProvider
```

How do I fix this mess?

Comment: did you register them both as providers inside the module ?

Comment: they are both registered in app.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

You have created circular dependency. You have to redesign your services so that they don't inject each other.